# Which one is the correct formula for Epanechnikov 4th order kernel?

Tags: kernel-smoothing

I read about this formula for Epanechnikov 4th order kernel in a book:

$k_b(u)=\frac{3}{4\sqrt{5}}(\frac{15}{8}-\frac{7}{8}u^2)(1-\frac{1}{5}u^2)\mathbf{1}(|u|\leq \sqrt{5})$

However, in a lecture note, the Epanechnikov 4th order kernel is written as follows:

$k_n(u)=\frac{3}{4}\frac{15}{8}(1-\frac{7}{3}u^2)(1-u^2)\mathbf{1}(|u|\leq 1)$

Do a change of variable $u=\frac{t}{\sqrt{5}}$

we get

$k^*_n(t)=k_{n}(\frac{t}{\sqrt{5}})=\frac{3}{4}\frac{15}{8}(1-\frac{7}{15}t^2)(1-\frac{1}{5}t^2)\mathbf{1}(|t|\leq \sqrt{5})=\frac{3}{4}(\frac{15}{8}-\frac{7}{8}t^2)(1-\frac{1}{5}t^2)\mathbf{1}(|t|\leq \sqrt{5})$,

which is still different from $k_{b}(u)$ by a constant factor of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$. In kernel regression they shouldn't make a difference as the constant factor will appear on the numerator and denominator and be canceled out. But certainly they will give different kernel density estimation.

So I'm wondering which one is correct, $k_{b}(\cdot)$ or $k^*_{n}(\cdot)$? Thanks!

Comment: You haven't changed variables in a way that preserves the area of the kernel.  In so doing, you omitted introducing the factor of $1/\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: @whuber Thanks. Can I interpret the need to include this factor as follows: $g(u)=\sqrt{5}u=t$, $u=g^{-1}(t)=\frac{t}{\sqrt{5}}$, the change of variable formula for pdf gives $k^*_{n}(t)=k_{n}(g^{-1}(t))|\frac{dg^{-1}(t)}{dt}|=k_{n}(\frac{t}{\sqrt{5}})\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$. But my question is here $k_{n}(\cdot)$ is no longer a pdf as it can take negative values, so is the interpretation using change of variable formula for pdf still valid?

Comment: The way change of variable in a function works doesn't rely on it being a pdf.

Comment: @Glen_b Does it come from change of variable theorem for integration?

Comment: If by that you mean the thing discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Definite_integrals) or [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChangeofVariablesTheorem.html), then sure. That's not unique to densities, if you like it's about how small "areas" scale.

Comment: Yes, you can view it as coming from integration.  I find it works well -- both conceptually and practically -- simply to remember that a kernel, a PDF, and any other quantity you would integrate against, also includes a "$\mathrm{d}x$" term and so you should always write it explicitly.  When you change the variable from $x$ to $y=y(x)$, $\mathrm{d}x$ changes to $\mathrm{d}y=y^\prime(x)\mathrm{d}x,$ forcing you to remember to include the factor of $y^\prime(x).$